# RegEx match all website links except those containing admin

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm setting up URL Rewrite on an IIS and i need to match the following URLs using regex.

```
http://sub.mysite.com
sub.mysite.com
sub.mysite.com/
sub.mysite.com/Site1
sub.mysite.com/Site1/admin
```

but not:

```
sub.mysite.com/admin
sub.mysite.com/admin/somethingelse
sub.mysite.com/admin/admin
```

The site it self (`sub.mysite.com`) should not be "hardcoded" in the expression. Instead, it should be matched by something like `.*`.

I'm really blank on this one. I did find solutions to match the different URLs but once i try to combine them either none of them match or all of them do.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: It's easier to match URLs with `/admin/` and took every other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your specific case, assuming you are matching the part after the domain (REQUEST_URI):

`(?!/admin).*`

`(?!...)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). I am not sure if it is supported in the IIS URL Rewrite engine. If not, a better approach would be to check for a complementary approach:

Or as @kirilloid said, just match `/admin/?` and discard (pay attention to slashes).

BTW. if you want to quickly test RegExps with a "visual" feedback, I highly recommend http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: IIS rewrite engine does support path from site root (i.e. w/o domain) like Apache, don't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+.)+.com(?!/admin)/?([A-Za-z0-9]+/?)*
```

this should do the trick